# ruby 1.9.1 error after installing compass gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass-sass

I installed compass on ubuntu 12.04 like so:

```
sudo gem install compass
sudo gem install sass
```

But after running this command:

```
compass version
```

I get this error:

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`rescue in require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in`'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in`each'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in`'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in`each'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in`block in '
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in`'
>           from /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
>           from /usr/bin/compass:23:in`'

when i run this:

```
ruby -v
```

I get:

> ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

What need to be fixed here.

## Solution:

As mentioned below:

```
gem uninstall compass
gem uninstall sass
gem install compass
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass
```

and that what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uninstall sass and reinstall it with the following:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass
```

For some reason

```
gem install compass
```

brings along some bleeding edge version of sass which is pony.

Comment: I had to use sudo to install sass because of a `Gem::FilePermissionError` but still the same thing.

Comment: hmm it's what worked for me, sorry i cant help further

Comment: My bad, I was installing sass after installing compass, after uninstalling both and then: `gem install compass`, `gem uninstall sass`, then `gem install sass`, it worked, thanks.